# mysql count function problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which is formatted as:

```
id |  food  | userID | beerID
```

I am trying to select all the foods for a given beerID and a count of repeats. SO if there are 3 entries for pizza I get results like:

```
food      | beerID | count

pizza     | 34     | 2
hot wings | 34     | 1
pasta     | 34     | 5
```

Does this work? I am a bit confused on using the count with the group by.

```
select food, beerID , count() where beerID = 34 group by food
```

Comment: General note about `GROUP BY`: You should include in the `GROUP BY` clause all of the columns in the `SELECT` clause (and vice versa), the exception being any aggregate functions being applied to each group (such as `COUNT(*)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `count` a parameter.

```
select food, beerID, count(food) from tablename as num where beerID = 34 group by food;
```

Footnote: "does this work" is a bad question. You'll 100% chance be rebutted with "did you not try it..?"

As noted in the comments you aren't selecting from a specific table, so it will error out

Comment: Wow totally missed that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT food, beerID, count(1) as beerCount
    FROM tablename
    WHERE beerID=34
    GROUP BY food;
```